# Empty input type not being posted in html

Tags: php, html, post, input

I created a PHP function that will create a form for any table that you have in a database. This function allows you to specify the name of the table and a list of all the columns you want in your html form. Everything works great, if the user puts something in for the text inputs. If they don't, then strange things happen when trying to retrieve the column name. Please see the function below...

```
function generateSubmissionFromTable($db, $tablename, $rowstoinclude,$action)
    {
        $query = 'SHOW COLUMNS from '.$tablename;   
        $colsresult = mysql_query($query,$db);

        $table = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($colsresult))
        {
            array_push($table,$row[0]);
        }

        $finalcolumns = array();
        foreach($table as $row)
        {
            foreach($rowstoinclude as $inc)
            {
                if($row == $inc)
                {
                    array_push($finalcolumns,$row);
                }
            }
        }
        echo '<form name="loginy" method="post" action="'.$action.'">';
        foreach($finalcolumns as $column)
        {
            echo 'Please enter the '.$column.'<br/>';
            echo '<input type=text name=column['.$column.'] value="blah"/><br/>';
        }
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="tablename" value="'.$tablename.'" />';         
        echo '<button type="button" size="4" style="font-size:35px;" onClick="document.loginy.submit()">Submit</button>';
        echo '</form>';
    }
```

Now, comes the weird part... I have another function that will generate the query statement based off that automatic form generation.

```
function submitDataToTable($post)
    {
        $query = 'INSERT INTO '.$post['tablename'].'(';
        $buf = "";
        while($col = current($post['column']))
        {
            $query = $query.$buf.key($post['column']);
            $buf=",";
            next($post['column']);
        }

        $buf = "";
        $query = $query.') VALUES (';
        foreach($post['column'] as $val)
        {
            $query = $query.$buf.$val;
            $buf = ",";
        }
        $query = $query.')';
        echo 'QUERY='.$query;
    }
```

Now for example I have a table that I want to input for 3 columns (name, link, descritpion) and I fill in the top 2 and not the bottom, the query gets generated as this...

```
QUERY=INSERT INTO LinksWebsites(name,link) VALUES (blah,blah,)
```

which as you can see, the query is missing the column (name,link,descritption) but what is weird if you take a look at the post...

```
POST =Array ( [column] => Array ( [name] => blah [link] => blah [description] => ) [tablename] => LinksWebsites )
```

which shows all the keys, but my PHP method of extracting the keys is not showing all the keys! (Might have something to do with the current($array) and key($array) calls?)

Comment: Wow. I would never use this code and recommend you stop using it too. It is vulnerable to SQL injection. `mysql_` functions are deprecated and you should either use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: Why is on  `ah,blah,) ` separator `,` at and of line?

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk besides the actual calls that make the SQL statements is there anything else wrong with the code? I am working off of PHP for dummies so I don't have too much experience with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a java script in your **html** where you will put the php function that text inputs must not be blank before trying to submit it.

```
    <script>
    function validateForm()
    {
    if (inputbox==null || inputbox=="")
    {alert("Input should not be empty");
    return false; 
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Just include the `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` in the form tag.